# Unable to locate a Java Runtime when neo4j-admin load

Tags: neo4j

when I try to load data to neo4j use

```
sudo neo4j-admin load --from=/Users/pmzz/Downloads/MyProjects/neo4j-nosql-front/base/graph.db.dump --database=pragh.db --force
```

it says

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

I've checked my java environment：

```
(base) ➜  ~ java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.48+21-CA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.48+21-CA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

and neo4j works fine:

```
(base) ➜  ~ neo4j start
Active database: graph.db
Directories in use:
  home:         /usr/local/neo4j
  config:       /usr/local/neo4j/conf
  logs:         /usr/local/neo4j/logs
  plugins:      /usr/local/neo4j/plugins
  import:       /usr/local/neo4j/import
  data:         /usr/local/neo4j/data
  certificates: /usr/local/neo4j/certificates
  run:          /usr/local/neo4j/run
Starting Neo4j.
Started neo4j (pid 5249). It is available at http://localhost:7474/
There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
See /usr/local/neo4j/logs/neo4j.log for current status.
```

my enviroment:

- macOS  bigsur on M1 chip
- neo4j 3.5.28 community
- java 11.0.11

**any advice？**